# Loader while loading data in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, load

I would like to display a loader (simple gif logo) while data is loading. In my app I use a function in a service class to get data in JSON thanks to a url (a webservice). Then, I call this function in an other class to inject the data in an array.

My function in service.ts:

```
  getData() {          
    return   this.http
                 .get(myUrl,/*headers*/)
                 .map((res:Response) => res.json());
 }
```

My function in class.ts:

```
array : any;

getData() {
this.service.getData()
  .subscribe(
  data => {    
    this.array = data;
  },
  err => console.error(err)
);
}
```

class.html :

```
<li *ngFor="let element of array"> {{element}}</li>
```

Maybe I could use `*ngIf` in .html and use a boolean variable to display the loader or the data but how to know when the data is completly loaded and when it is not ?

Thanks by advance for any help !

Answer (score 3):

`*ngIf` with a boolean state is fine. `subscribe(...)` supports an `onComplete` callback:

```
getData() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.service.getData()
  .subscribe(
    data => {    
      this.array = data;
      // this.isLoading = false;
    },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => this.isLoading = false;
  );
}
```

Resetting the state in the first callback (where I added it as comment) is fine as well because `Http` only delivers a single event. For observables that deliver more than one event the 3rd callback might be a better fit because it is called when the observable is closed and no more events will be sent.